# Calling macro in java

Tags: excel, vba

im new to java programing.

I want to create a simple program that reads a .xls / .xlsx document, calls a macro, and saves the file. Im using org.apache.poi and everything seems fine except for calling a macro. Ive been looking up for some tips on forums but found nothing.

macro was created before and its saved. i just have a lot of documents and dont want to do it manually.

in Java Ive created a workbook, created a sheet. How to call a macro to be done? should i refer to a workbook or sheet itself?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this:

- Launch Excel via ProcessBuilder and have Excel run the Macro and Save the file. To run the macro you may need add a little VBA (e.g. in the AutoOpen Sub).
- There are also tools to call Java from Excel ( [Obba](http://www.obba.info) or [XLLoop](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net) ). You could call Java form VBA, then the Macro, then save the file.

Comment: In order to have Excel execute the macros, this assumes you have Excel on the machine you are running your code on.

If this is running in a server based environment, keep in mind Microsoft themselves do not recommend Office Automation on the sever http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. POI is a library to read/edit Office files. It will preserve any macros that exists in the file, but it does not have an interpreter built in to run macros.